# [[FATAL]] [[DBT-06103]] The port (5,500) is already in use in Docker Container

Tags: linux, oracle, docker, oracle19c

I'm trying to use Oracle 19c DB Container for my test cases in Jenkins Job but DB Container is intermittently failing with this error

```
[FATAL] [DBT-06103] The port (5,500) is already in use.
   ACTION: Specify a free port.
```

I referred to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268437/fatal-dbt-06103-the-port-5-500-is-already-in-use?newreg=335276877b8c4859a5fd41263b960125) but how can I achieve this in container where hostname is always dynamic?

Comment: "intermittently failing"  probably when more test is running at once.       If you're running the tests in docker as well, you don't need to forward a port at all.  Otherwise if you need prot forwarding,  docker can allocate a random port for you and then you can introspect the container to see which port to tell your application to use.

Comment: Its failing at start itself while creating container

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following this solution:

Solution
Just add an IP mapping to `/etc/hosts` for hostname resolution.

open `/etc/hosts` then add the host to ip mapping

```
10.10.10.10 ora19c ora19c.example.com
```

https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-dbt-06103-the-port-5500-is-already-in-use/